# Emulsifying starchy vegetables

Tags: sauce, emulsion, pumpkin, squash, starch

What is the general process of emulsification of starchy vegetables, pumpkin and squash in particular, into shiny and oily pasta sauces?

My **first attempt** was:

1. Pressure-cook the flesh (until soft enough for mashing)
2. Mash and mix with heavy cream, butter, vegetable oil and starchy pasta water

The result had consistency of a soup rather than sauce.

For my **second attempt** I plan to use a blender:

1. Mix pasta water and heavy cream
2. Add and mix in cooked pumpkin flesh
3. Slowly pour vegetable oil while blending

Is this a viable idea? In the end I want consistency of https://www.bonappetit.com/recipe/creamy-pumpkin-pasta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I would expect the Bon Appetit recipe to result in a greasy soup as written.  It has both too much oil, and too much pasta water in it.

The standard way to make a "creamy" pumpkin sauce for pasta is to [thicken it with a white sauce](https://spainonafork.com/creamy-pumpkin-pasta-crazy-delicious-20-minute-pasta-recipe/). This is an extremely reliable way to make sure that the sauce emulsifies together and does not break.

Comment: Do you suggest to have an emulsified sauce at hand to mix with vegetable flesh, thus effectively coating it with emulsion rather than creating an emulsion?

Comment: Specifically a white sauce.  A mayonnaise or hollandaise is just going to break when you dump in all that pumpkin.